# HTTP Delay from AWS Instance to Bitmex with Boost Beast and Ubuntu 18

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, http, boost-beast, bitmex

I have an AWS ec2 instance in eu-west-1c which is the same data centre as the target server - [www.bitmex.com](http://www.bitmex.com). If I run `$ping bitmex.com` from the instance the average round trip time is ~0.4 milliseconds. The same is true for `$ping bitmex.com/api/v1` (to test the API endpoint specifically). However, when I run http requests to `bitmex.com/api/v1/order/bulk` from some c++ code the round trip time is never better than ~10 milliseconds but that's a rare case and the time taken for the majority of requests is in the hundreds of milliseconds or more. This makes the difference between those calls and the ping time something like 1000x slower.

These messages are specifically to & from the order engine (as a result of the /order/bulk endpoint) so I get that some delay can be associated to the fact that the server on the other end has some processing to do. However I have never seen it be this slow before - previously when profiling this I observed the time for requests to the same endpoint to be in the same region as the ping time, if not faster on occasion. This delay is also present regardless of the market's activity and therefore how busy the bitmex endpoint is.

This has lead me to wonder whether the problem is with my code, the http library in use, the setup of the AWS instance or something else. A key point here I think is that I tested the same program in a python version using pycurl as the http library and it actually outperformed the c++ version slightly on round-trip time, I know this has nothing to do with python vs. c++ as it's the time for the message to travel on the wire and back again (ignoring what the kernel and http libraries are doing under the hood), the purpose was just to test a different language and http library to see if the problem was there. The python code managed to get a few messages back in 1 millisecond or close to, so it's best-case performance was around 10x faster than the best case of the c++ code. It also had slower messages in the region of 1-200 milliseconds but never as slow as the c++ version.

The next thing I've tried in c++ was to read the header first and then the body, in case Beast (the http library I'm using) was waiting for the end of the body for a while. Profiling showed that the delay is entirely between sending the request and actually receiving any bytes back again. I found this from observing that the time taken for the header read is in the 100's of milliseconds and then the body read takes literally microseconds at most. So the data for the body must already have been on the machine and ready to go when the call to read was made but there was a wait for the header/the initial bytes of the message.

Therefore I'm wondering what could be causing this - is anyone else experiencing the same latency to this endpoint of the bitmex API? Can anyone provide any advice on how to debug this or what might be causing the latency?

Setup:

- AWS instance is running Ubuntu Server 18
- c++17 compiled using g++9 on ubuntu 20 (my local machine), then scp to the AWS instance and run there
- Boost Beast library for http using only asynchronous calls
- All calls are https

Other things I've tried and tested:

- Ubuntu 20 vs. 18 - no difference
- Boost asio handler tracker - couldn't get it to work/don't know where or how to see the output from it
- cURL c++ http library - no difference

Here is a stripped-back version of my application that should compile and run with the command used to compile it included on line 1 - to get it to successfully open orders on the exchange you'd need to add an API key and secret which are declared as member variables of the class. This code connects to bitmex.com, keeps the connection alive and sends 5 identical orders to bitmex.com/api/v1/bulk and prints the response time to the console:

```
// g++ -std=c++17 -pthread -o http_test.out http_test.cpp -lssl -lcrypto && ./http_test.out

//Boost & Beast headers
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/core.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/version.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
#include <boost/beast/websocket/ssl.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/connect.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ssl/stream.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

//REST headers
#include <sstream>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

//Misc. headers
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace beast     = boost::beast;         // from <boost/beast.hpp>
namespace http      = beast::http;          // from <boost/beast/http.hpp>
namespace websocket = beast::websocket;     // from <boost/beast/websocket.hpp>
namespace net       = boost::asio;          // from <boost/asio.hpp>
namespace ssl       = boost::asio::ssl;     // from <boost/asio/ssl.hpp>
using     tcp       = boost::asio::ip::tcp; // from <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>

using namespace std;


class BitMEX_MM : public std::enable_shared_from_this<BitMEX_MM> {
    
    int n_tests = 1;
    
    //REST
    tcp::resolver rest_resolver;
    beast::ssl_stream<beast::tcp_stream> rest_stream;
    beast::flat_buffer rest_buffer;
    
    http::request<http::string_body>  post_req;
    http::response<http::string_body> post_res;
    
    string limit_order_msg  = "{\"orders\":[";
    
    // Timing
    struct timespec start, end;
    
    //MEMBER VARIABLES
    string apiKey    = ""; //FILL IN API KEY
    string apiSecret = ""; //FILL IN API SEC
    int    apiKeyLen = apiKey.length();
    const char* apiKeyCStr = apiKey.c_str();
    int    apiSecLen = apiSecret.length();
    const char* apiSecCStr = apiSecret.c_str();
    int    expiry_t  = 5;
    
    //REST FUNCTIONS
    static size_t WriteCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
    {
        ((string*)userp)->append((char*)contents, size * nmemb);
        return size * nmemb;
    }
    
    string HMAC_SHA256_hex_POST(string valid_till)
    {
        string data = "POST/api/v1/order/bulk" + valid_till + limit_order_msg;
        
        stringstream ss;
        unsigned int len;
        unsigned char out[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
        HMAC_CTX *ctx = HMAC_CTX_new();
        HMAC_Init_ex(ctx, apiSecCStr, apiSecLen, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
        HMAC_Update(ctx, (unsigned char*)data.c_str(), data.length());
        HMAC_Final(ctx, out, &len);
        HMAC_CTX_free(ctx);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        {
            ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << hex << (unsigned int)out[i];
        }
        return ss.str();
    }
    
    void
    REST_on_resolve(
        beast::error_code ec,
        tcp::resolver::results_type results)
    {
        // Make the connection on the IP address we get from a lookup
        beast::get_lowest_layer(rest_stream).async_connect(
            results,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &BitMEX_MM::REST_on_connect,
                shared_from_this()));
    }

    void
    REST_on_connect(beast::error_code ec,
                    tcp::resolver::results_type::endpoint_type)
    {       
        // Perform the SSL handshake
        rest_stream.async_handshake(
            ssl::stream_base::client,
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &BitMEX_MM::REST_on_handshake,
                shared_from_this()));
    }
    
    void
    REST_on_handshake(beast::error_code ec)
    {       
        limit_order_msg += "{\"symbol\":\"XBTUSD\",\"ordType\":\"Limit\",\"execInst\":\"ParticipateDoNotInitiate\",\"clOrdID\":\"" + to_string(n_tests) \
                        + "\",\"side\":\"Buy\",\"price\":10.0" \
                        + ",\"orderQty\":2}]}";
        REST_write_limit_order_bulk();
    }
    
    void REST_write_limit_order_bulk()
    {
        int valid_till        = time(0) + 5;
        string valid_till_str = to_string(valid_till);
        
        post_req.set("api-expires", valid_till_str);
        post_req.set("api-signature", HMAC_SHA256_hex_POST(valid_till_str));
        post_req.set("Content-Length", to_string(limit_order_msg.length()));
        post_req.body() = limit_order_msg;
        
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
        
        http::write(rest_stream, post_req);
        http::read(rest_stream, rest_buffer, post_res);
        
        beast::error_code _ec;
        std::size_t       _bt;
        process_limit_order_bulk_res(_ec, _bt);
    }
    
    void process_limit_order_bulk_res(beast::error_code ec,
                                      std::size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
        double time_taken;
        time_taken = (end.tv_sec  - start.tv_sec) + ((end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) * 1e-9);
        cout << "response time: " << time_taken << endl;
        
        ++n_tests;
        
        if (n_tests <= 5)
        {
            limit_order_msg  = "{\"orders\":[";
            limit_order_msg += "{\"symbol\":\"XBTUSD\",\"ordType\":\"Limit\",\"execInst\":\"ParticipateDoNotInitiate\",\"clOrdID\":\"" + to_string(n_tests) \
                            + "\",\"side\":\"Buy\",\"price\":10.0" \
                            + ",\"orderQty\":2}]}";
            REST_write_limit_order_bulk();
        }
    }
    
public:
        
    explicit
    BitMEX_MM(net::io_context& rest_ioc, ssl::context& rest_ctx)
        : rest_resolver(net::make_strand(rest_ioc)),
        rest_stream(net::make_strand(rest_ioc), rest_ctx)
    { }
    
    void
    run_REST_service()
    {           
        // Set SNI Hostname (many hosts need this to handshake successfully)
        if(! SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(rest_stream.native_handle(), "www.bitmex.com"))
        {
            beast::error_code ec{static_cast<int>(::ERR_get_error()), net::error::get_ssl_category()};
            std::cerr << "ssl err " << ec.message() << "\n";
            return;
        }
        
        // Set up an HTTP GET request message
        post_req.version(11);
        post_req.method(http::verb::post);
        post_req.target("/api/v1/order/bulk");
        post_req.set(http::field::host, "www.bitmex.com");
        post_req.set(http::field::user_agent, BOOST_BEAST_VERSION_STRING);
        post_req.set(http::field::accept, "*/*");
        post_req.set(http::field::content_type, "application/json");
        post_req.set(http::field::connection, "Keep-Alive");
        post_req.set("api-key", "");
        post_req.insert("Content-Length", "");
        post_req.insert("api-expires", "");
        post_req.insert("api-signature", "");
        
        // Look up the domain name
        rest_resolver.async_resolve(
            "www.bitmex.com",
            "443",
            beast::bind_front_handler(
                &BitMEX_MM::REST_on_resolve,
                shared_from_this()));
                
    }
    
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
    net::io_context rest_ioc;
    ssl::context    rest_ctx{ssl::context::tlsv12_client};
    
    auto algo = make_shared<BitMEX_MM>(rest_ioc, rest_ctx);
    
    cout << "Running http test." << endl;
    
    algo->run_REST_service();
    
    rest_ioc.run();
    
    return 0;
}
```

The results for me from the collocated server:

```
Running http test.
response time: 0.0110592
response time: 0.00464095
response time: 0.00503278
response time: 0.00440869
response time: 0.00362543
```

Seems what you'd expect, the first response takes longer due to establishing connection with the server. After that response time is much quicker but still ~10x more than the ping time. It's really variable however, another time running it gives:

```
Running http test.
response time: 0.288384
response time: 0.188272
response time: 0.133779
response time: 0.0540737
response time: 0.0179791
```

Much slower.

Comment: If you want us to improve your code you'll have to provide a [mre]. Do you have compiler optimisations enabled?

Comment: @AlanBirtles sure, I'll post something up. That's a good point - I am using the -OFast compiler optimisation. This is my full command to compile the code: g++ -std=c++17 -pthread -Ofast -o BitMEX_MM.out BitMEX_MM.cpp simdjson.cpp -lssl -lcrypto -lcurl

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've added a cut-down version of my code that just sends 5 orders to the exchange with some example results that I get.

Comment: Probably entirely dependant on the load of the server you're talking to, it takes time to compute the response

Comment: @jp94 did you solved this problem, please let me know why it has slowed down in your cpp code, i am too using boost.beast ! advance thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If this is your command line:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pthread -o http_test.out http_test.cpp -lssl -lcrypto && ./http_test.out
```

Aren't you missing "-O2"? It looks like you are building without optimizations. Which will be considerably slower.

Comment: did you tested it out ? @Vinnie Falco ? i dont think he will be returning anytime soon. This is an old post

Comment: I haven't tested it but in case someone else reads the question, they will now have a possible answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what i know of bitmex engine, having a latency around 10ms for order execution is the best you can get, and it will be worse during high volatility periods. Check https://bonfida.com/latency-monitor to get an idea of latencies. On crypto world, latency are far higher than traditional hft